# Where do I find the campaign trail for Donald Trump?

Tags: united-states, president, campaigning, donald-trump

How do I find out if Donald Trump is coming to a place near me?

I went to his web-site, https://www.DonaldJTrump.com/, *"Make America Great Again! | Donald J Trump for President"*, but there does not appear to be any systemic information about neither past nor present campaign trail stops anywhere.

Comment: @PointlessSpike, I just don't like "here" links that don't have any useful content within.  Please link to a site that actually works, and don't use a "here" link.

Comment: I'm trying to narrow down what you're looking for. Do you mean mentioning the name of the site being linked to? Because there's not much else we can provide.

Comment: Isn't there an "Events" link in the top corner of his website?

Comment: @Bobson, lol, you're right! :-)  I guess paying 3$ for a web-site doesn't result in a good website, either! :-)

Comment: @Bobson, please feel free to provide a full answer!

Comment: @PointlessSpike - I'm not sure why the website you linked to wasn't working for some people, but I included it with a screenshot in my answer.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Nope, it's a much better answer anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of what you're looking for is actually on the official website you linked to, although it's an easy link to miss.  See the screenshot below for the location of the [**Events**](http://www.donaldjtrump.com/events/) link.

[image: Trump website, Events highlighted]

The Events page seems to only list *upcoming* events, not previous ones, so it won't tell you where he's been.  I also found [blog.4president.us](http://blog.4president.us/2016/donald-trump/), which appears to be trying to track all the news about all the candidates, and it includes (under the linked-to tag) posts about all his previous stops.  It is, however, not working temporarily right now, but screenshot of when it worked is below. [image: Previous Trump events]

Finally, there's [trumpstump2016.com](http://trumpstump2016.com/donalds-itinerary/), originally provided by PointlessSpike.  Some people have had problems accessing it (update: not anymore), but it's working fine for me.  Your mileage may vary, but you can see what it's supposed to look like below.

[image: Trump calendar]

Comment: Cool, thanks!  BTW, TrumpStump finally started working, even though it didn't before.  However, your blog.4president.us, the whole site even, returns straight 404 for me!.